# Getting firebase data for each string in an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase Realtime Database, I have a node labelled "groups" and this is how I constructed it:

[image: Groups Node - Firebase]

Underneath the "users" above, I'm trying to use those userIds to reference the data within each user. This is how I constructed each "users" node I'm trying to reference:

[image: Users Node - Firebase]

In the below code snippet, I get the userIds from a snapshot of the groups' users child node. And then I run a for-in loop on those userIds to access the information in the "users" node.

The `print("This should be the individual userId: ", userId)` statement prints out each userId correctly. And the `userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in` gets called the first time the for-in loop is called, but it's almost like it's ignored. The app crashes because the user array comes up empty at the end. However, a ridiculous amount of empty users show up in the array (when looking at the Variables View in the Debug Area). So, i feel like I'm running some form of a redundant loop or something.

```
guard let groupChatPartnerId = message.chatPartnerId() else {
    return
}

var users: [User]?

let ref = Database.database().reference().child("groups").child(groupChatPartnerId)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let groupId = snapshot.key

    let groupName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "groupName").value as! String

    let userIdDictionary = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "users").value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    let userIds = Array(userIdDictionary.keys)
    print("userIds: ", userIds)



    for userId in userIds {
        print("This should be the individual userId: ", userId)
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("This is the snapshot: ", snapshot)
            let email: String = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
            print("user's email: ", email)
            let uid = snapshot.key
            let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String
            let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String

            let user = User(uid: uid, userUsername: username, userProfileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, userEmail: email)

            users?.append(user)
            print("user to append to users: ", user)

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

    print("users :", users)

    let group = Group(groupId: groupId, groupName: groupName, users: users!)
    self.showChatControllerForGroup(group: group)

}, withCancel: nil)
```

Let me know if you need any other information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

All data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously By the time your print `users`, none of the `userRef.observeSingleEvent` has completed yet. So the code to print all users must be inside the completion handle of `userRef.observeSingleEvent` and must only run once all users have been loaded.

A simple way to do that is to compare the length of `users` with the length of `userIds`. If they're the same, you've loaded all users:

```
for userId in userIds {
    print("This should be the individual userId: ", userId)
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("This is the snapshot: ", snapshot)
        let email: String = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
        print("user's email: ", email)
        let uid = snapshot.key
        let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String
        let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String

        let user = User(uid: uid, userUsername: username, userProfileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, userEmail: email)

        users?.append(user)
        print("user to append to users: ", user)

        if userIds.count == users.count {
            print("users :", users)
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Comment: the problem I'm having is that it seems like `userRef.observeSingleEvent` isn't being called because `print("This is the snapshot: ", snapshot)` and all the other print statements in the compeltion handle of `userRef.observeSingleEvent` aren't being printed.

Comment: i was thinking that since the "users" values in "groups" isn't changed, that's why it isn't being called. At least that's what the Firebase documentation led me to believe

Comment: I'm confused. In your question you said that `userRef.observeSingleEvent` *does* get called, and my answer doesn't change anything about that. All I've done is move the printing of the array *into* that callback, and make it dependent on the number of users that has been loaded.

Comment: so, when I put a breakpoint at `userRef.observeSingleEvent`, the breakpoint stops on that line but nothing inside it ever gets called. sorry about the confusion! Does this make more sense?

Comment: And this doesn't make sense to me because whenever I've tried to read info from the Firebase Database, I've gotten a snapshot with `observeSingleEvent` and then gotten the data from that. But here the info within the `observeSingleEvent`'s completion handle isn't even being called